# Logstash pipeline data is not pushed to Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

> input {[image]

file {

```
    path => "/home/blusapphire/padma/sampledata.csv"

    start_position => "beginning"

    }
```

}

filter {

```
 csv {

   columns => [ "First_Name", "Last_Name", "Age", "Salary", "Emailid", "Gender" ]

    }
```

}

output {

elasticsearch {

```
      hosts => ["${ES_INGEST_HOST_02}:9200"]

      index => "network"

      user  => "adcd"

      password => "adcbdems"  
}
```

}

This my logstash config file, and when running logstash file I'm not seeing data (which is given csv) in Elasticsearch, and index is not creating, Is there any mistake in configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your screenshot, it is clear that logstash has noticed your file. To get logstash to feel it is making "first contact" with the file, try:

1. shutdown logstash
2. delete the since_db file
3. start up logstash

Alternatively, move the file outside the monitored folder, execute the above steps and then drop the file in.

Can you also confirm that your set up works with other files - just in case?